# Button image not centering vertically

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, imagebutton

I have subclassed a button such that I can get basically a button with rounded edges and an icon on the right side.

Nearly got it right, only issue is that the icon is not centered vertically and cannot seem to figure out how I can influence the vertical alignment.

The original image is rectangular and I am using CreateResizableImage with a pre-defined UIEdgeInsets struct as below but what I am seeing is:

[image]

MY subclass code is:

```
partial class CustomGreyButton : UIButton
    {
        public CustomGreyButton (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {
            this.Layer.BorderColor = new CoreGraphics.CGColor (0, 0, 0);
            this.Layer.BorderWidth = 1;
            this.Layer.CornerRadius = 20;

            // top, left, bottom, right
            UIEdgeInsets btnEdgeInsets = new UIEdgeInsets (0,44,0,44);

            UIImage stretchingButtonImage = new UIImage ("ios_images/grey_btn.png").CreateResizableImage (btnEdgeInsets);


            this.SetBackgroundImage (stretchingButtonImage, UIControlState.Normal);
            this.SetBackgroundImage (stretchingButtonImage, UIControlState.Selected);
            this.SetBackgroundImage (stretchingButtonImage, UIControlState.Highlighted);
            this.ClipsToBounds = true;
            this.AdjustsImageWhenHighlighted = false;

            //this.TitleColor = UIColor.White;
            this.SetTitleColor (UIColor.White, UIControlState.Normal);
            this.SetTitleColor (UIColor.Black, UIControlState.Highlighted);
            this.SetTitleColor (UIColor.Black, UIControlState.Selected);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you upload the graphic you are trying to add. Your UIEdgeInsets don't look right but it is difficult to tell without seeing the graphic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much trial and error found out that this seems to work for my code:

```
UIImage stretchingButtonImage = new UIImage ("ios_images/grey_btn.png");

stretchingButtonImage.ImageWithAlignmentRectInsets (btnEdgeInsets);
```

Seems I shouldn't have been using

> CreateResizableImage

Answer (score 1):

I found the same problem on [xamarin forum](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/20646/how-to-vertically-center-an-item-in-a-grid-cell)

As a understand, you should put YAlign="Center" on your Image

Comment: Sorry, not using Xamarin.Forms, I should have stipulated.